# How would you make a comprehensive list of Google domains?

Tags: google

If you wanted to block access of a single machine to all sites whose domain is owned or controlled by Google, how would you go about generating a comprehensive list to add to /etc/hosts?  How would you handle Google Apps sites?

Comment: Why do you want to block access to Google?  Depending upon your real goals/purpose, there may be better ways to achieve it.

Comment: May be related to http://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain , some answers there will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a better solution would be to lookup the IP classes owned (registered) by Google and blacklist (deny) them in a firewall (iptables).

To get the IP classes owned by Google, you could start by gathering IP addresses from different classes (maybe using DNS to resolve different well-known Google domains) and using one of the many online WHOIS services ([an example](http://all-nettools.com/toolbox/smart-whois.php)) which indicate how much of that class (the subnet mask) is owned by Google.

Just a side note: getting the IP classes is not quite practical and probably not the only way. Not sure if you can find them somewhere already published...